# Sonata Block Bundle is having trouble finding my new class

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am trying to create a new block service using Sonata Block Bundle. It is running atop Symfony 3.3.

I have cloned my existing `TextBlockService.php` file into a new file called `CenteredOverlineBlockService.php`. Both files reside in the `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/` directory.

I have added the following text to my `blocks.yml` file:

```
vgms.block.centeredoverline:
    class: AppBundle\Block\CenteredOverlineBlockService
    arguments:
        - "Centered Overline"
        - "@templating"
        - "@sonata.media.manager.media"
        - "@sonata.admin.pool"
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.block }
```

... and I have added the following reference in `sonata_block.yml`:

```
    vgms.block.centeredoverline:
```

... and I now get the following error:

> Attempted to load class "CenteredOverlineBlockService" from namespace
>   "AppBundle\Block". Did you forget a "use" statement for another
>   namespace?

So my question is: **What step am I missing here?**

The application loads the previously existing TextBlockService without complaint. It's only this new service that seems to create a problem.

===

Edit #1: Here is the top of the class involved:

```
namespace AppBundle\Block;

use ...

class CenteredOverlineBlockService extends \Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\TextBlockService
{
...
```

Comment: Does you revised your namespace in the CenteredOverlineBlockService.php class has been correctly setted?

Comment: Thanks, Jose -- I have edited the question to include the top of the class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, my "fix" was to clone a service from a *different* bundle and then use that class instead.

That doesn't really answer the "why" question I posed, but maybe it will hopeuflly help someone.